# SonarQube FxCop Analysis (rule: CA1704) throws issues even though we define CustomDictionary.xml under C# Project

Tags: c#, sonarqube, fxcop, sonarqube-5.0

When I ran sonar analysis for C# project, sonar reported few issues: one of the issue was from fxcop rule named **CA1704: Identifiers should be spelled correctly**. Since I did not wish sonar to report issues under rule *CA1704*, I created a CustomDictionary.xml and followed the instructions provided under *"How to fix violations"* for fxcop rule *CA1704*.

P.S: As per the instructions provided to fix violations for rule CA1704, we can place CustomDictionary.xml at any 3 places namely -

- Place the dictionary in the installation directory of the tool
- The project directory
- The directory that is associated with the tool under the profile of
  the user (%USERPROFILE%\Application Data...)

I chose 2nd option (above), placed CustomDictionary.xml inside C# project directory and ran sonar analysis in debug mode. After analyzing the log of sonar, when fxcop starts with its analysis on C# project - following log can be seen.

*Executing command: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe **/file**:D:\Installers\Example_Projects\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\csharp\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe **/ruleset**:=D:\Installers\Example_Projects\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\csharp.sonar\Sample_Test_Framework_ConsoleApplication1\fxcop-sonarqube.ruleset **/out**:D:\Installers\Example_Projects\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\csharp.sonar\Sample_Test_Framework_ConsoleApplication1\fxcop-report.xml **/outxsl**:none **/forceoutput** **/searchgac***

Even though I've placed CustomDictionary.xml inside C# project directory. **Sonar is unable to avoid the violations reported by rule CA1704; even if CustomDictionary.xml present under project directory.** By default (*referring to above log*), fxcop sonar analysis takes the default CustomDictionary.xml which is present at the installation directory of FxCop (here in this case *C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/*).

I have ran analysis on C# project with both sonar-runner 2.3 & 2.4 versions.

Is there any possibility how we can change the default dictionary path to another path where CustomDictionary.xml is present?

Would it be possible if there is a room for implementing a new sonar argument which takes custom path where CustomDictionary.xml is present?

Thank you, Dhruva

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your .csproj to tell FxCop which dictionary to use:

`<ItemGroup>
  <CodeAnalysisDictionary Include="MyCustomDictionary.xml" />
</ItemGroup>`